# app.exe.config file not published with ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, clickonce, app-config

I have a clickonce app that needs the app.config file deployed.
In Visual Studio, if I right click on the **app.config** file and select **properties** then change the **Build Action** to **Content**, the app.config.deploy file gets created, but there is no app.exe.config.deploy file.

I really don't even need the app.exe.config.deploy file and I don't know why Visual Studio (2010) includes it.

At this point, I click on the properties for the clickonce .csproj file, click on the **publish** tab and click on **Application Files**. "app.config" and "app.exe.config is set to "Include (auto)". But I don't have the option to disable the app.exe.config.

The reason I need app.config deployed is because I'm using the following code:

```
var str = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oem"];
```

I'm deploying multiple versions of this with an external build script. The build script swaps out different versions of the app.config for each different published version of the code.

Bottom line question. Is there a way to either:

1. Get the app.exe.config to deploy with the rest of the publish
2. Only get the app.config file to deploy (without the app.exe.config)

If I add say a text file to the project and set it's deployment type to "content" as specified above it gets included.